# htaccess rewrite only in root directory (generically)

Tags: .htaccess

Hi I am trying to get htaccess to rewrite only if a file, symlink, or a directory is not present with that name. Which I have successfully done with this right here:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+) - [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index\.php?var=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Works perfectly, however, I only want this to occur in the root directory, not in any subdirectories. How can I accomplish this in a generic way (meaning I don't want to explicitly state the URL in the .htaccess file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent any mod_rewrite directives being processed for requests outside of the document root then place the following rule at the top of the file:

```
# Prevent further processing if the request is outside the root directory
RewriteRule / - [L]
```

The above basically states that for any requested URL-path that contains a slash then stop here. (This will also catch requests that end in a slash - is that an issue?)

---

Alternatively, you can make the regex on the existing two rules more specific so that it only applies to requests in the root directory.

For example:

```
# Only apply rules to requests in the root directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^[^/]+$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?var=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The `PT` flag on the first rule is not required. And the capturing group in the first rule is not required either. Literal dots in the *substitution* string do not need to be backslash-escaped.

NB: This will also fail to process requests that *end* with a slash.

---

However, if these are your only rules that are related to this then you don't  *need* two rules, only one is required, providing it is OK for requests to the document root itself being absent the `var` URL parameter. For example:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?var=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Note that the logic of the *conditions* is reversed.

As mentioned, requests for the root directory itself will just drop through to `index.php` (by mod_dir), not `index.php?var=`.

Comment: Great answer, thank you for the detailed response. Follow up question: what if I wanted to also process requests that do end in a slash, as long as that directory doesn't exist. is that possible?